Simulate hardware keyboard button press in Xcode UI test for iPad
XCUIElement has two methods named typeKey(_:modifierFlags:): the first one takes a String as an argument, the second one a XCUIKeyboardKey, which has constants like .downArrow. Now, even if the documentation says that both methods are "Available in macOS and in iPadOS 15 and later", when compiling the UI tests for iOS, the following line
app.typeKey(.downArrow, modifierFlags: [])

produces a compiler error
Type 'String' has no member 'downArrow'

Am I missing something or is there a workaround?

Xcode doesn't know the type of .downArrow so you need to explicitly state it:
app.typeKey(XCUIKeyboardKey.downArrow.rawValue, modifierFlags: [])

That doesn't seem to work. Do you have a working sample?

Can you provide some sample code? What kind of element are you trying to perform this on?

I've created a sample app, tested many things, and can confirm this doesn't seem to work despite compiling correctly and adhering to the documentation. I will file a radar w/ Apple.
